# Cygwin cpio doesn't work on Windows

Tags: cygwin, cpio

I have just installed cygwin on Windows 7 x64, and I have installed all the packages I need. I have installed `cpio`, and I am attempting to extract a file with the following command line in the cygwin console:

```
cpio -i -H newc /sygdrive/f/_virtual/image.cpio
```

When I run this, I get no errors, but nothing happens. No extraction. I first tried waiting 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 1 hour, the next evening, but nothing is happening. The cpio archive file is less then 20 MB. The system never ran out of RAM or CPU. It's like nothing happens. The console and the system are not locked. I can kill the command and move on.

What's the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cpio -i` reads from the standard input.  Try

```
cpio -i -H newc  <  /sygdrive/f/_virtual/image.cpio
```